# Is it useful to send a developer to attend a 3days Microsoft Learning Gateway Workshop?

Tags: language-agnostic

my company is very LAMP based as of now, and my management had decided to send a hardware guy and a developer to this MLG workshop. From what I check online it's mostly MS trying to bundle up a whole lot of their stuff and try to sell it to us to solve our problems.
Plus the fact that most of what we use now are pretty much open source tech, LAMP, purchased 3rd party libraries.

So I feel this is more of a management thingy rather that what a developer should attend. Have any you guys attended this? Or is this is waste of time as far as a developer need is. If it's not then I would probably talk to my team lead who's more managerial like than me to attend :P

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go there yourself. If you send managers there, MS could succeed in selling them stuff, and then you would be forced to use it.

Comment: @mad-j haha, that's makes perfect sense in a sad imperfect world kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

... I'm confused why any of you would bother attending this when you're an Open Source LAMP shop. Is a switch being considered??

Comment: @Spencer well according to the higher-ups they want to stay abreast of the state of the art..